# How to expose the visual force page with out using the portals and Communities

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, administration, developer

I need access a visual force page with out using salesforce credentials.

Comment: you can use auth 2.0 for authentication

Comment: Could you please explain me brief..

Answer (score 0):

you can give the page access to the site,from site you can access the page without using salesforce credentials.